# IPython env magic on Windows 7

Tags: windows, ipython

I'm on Windows 7, using IPython (0.12).

I am trying to mess with environment variables directly in IPython using the `%env` magic.

Listing ENV variables using `%env` works just fine. But trying to pass any options, or set/modify new variables has no effect. When additional arguments are passed the `env` magic function, its as if they are completely ignored.

The only help information says:

> %env:
>
> ```
>     List environment variables.
> ```

Is this a windows problem? Version 0.12 problem? Removed magic function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%env is a read-only magic - it just prints the current environment, you can't set anything with it. If you want to set environment variables, you can use `os.environ`:

```
import os
os.environ['NAME'] = 'VALUE'
```

Comment: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/shell.html#environment-variables  I am confused, the docs seem to contradict your answer. Is the documented %env functionality a recent development?

Comment: What I am really after is the ability to make changes to environment variables (within the context of that ipython session), and have these values apply to any shell commands, `!my_program.bat`. I know how to explicitly launch a new process with a prepared environment, but the idea is to use Ipython for quick and dirty changes in an 'interactive shell' usage pattern. Do other Ipython magics work cleanly with os.environ?

Comment: That doc page is way out of date, and used to have a big warning at the top to that effect. It describes functionality added by the shell *profile*, removed in 0.11. Everything works just fine with os.environ. If `env` adds support for setting environment variables, it would just be a shortcut for setting `os.environ` keys.